# In android compose, is using onClick of a button considered a side effect?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I saw the definition of side effect

> A side-effect is a change to the state of the app that happens outside the scope of a composable function.

how about Onclick method in button?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Counter() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Button(onClick = { count++ }) {
        Text("Count: $count")
    }
}
```

in that above example,
when i click the button, count increases and onClick is not composable function.
is it also side effect?

Comment: I would say you can class this as a side-effect yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A side-effect is a change to the state of the app that happens outside the scope of a composable function.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

an onClick lambda is not in scope of the composable, so yes it's a side-effect